# Error in shortest distance between points and lines

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using QGIS 2.18.4 in along with GRASS plugin to analyaze vector data. I have to shapefiles, 1) roads and 2) observation points. Both layers are as geographic coordinates (WGS 84). I need to know the closest distance between each point and a given line (the closest too). To acompish this, I thought of using the function v.distance of GRASS. First, I created a mapset in GRASS; then I loaded both files into the mapset using directly "add vector layer" in QGIS. Finally, when using the function "v.in.org.qgis" from GRASS to load the roads, the following error pops up:

```
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.0/bin/v.in.ogr.exe 
"input=C:\Users\lucianolasala\Documents\Analysis\Wild 
boars\Shapefiles\Roads\Red Vial\002_Red_Vial.shp" output=Red snap=-1 
min_area=0.0001 -o --o
Over-riding projection check

Check if OGR layer <002_Red_Vial> contains polygons...
￼Vector map already exists and will be overwritten
Table linked to vector map does not exist
Unable to create table: 'create table Red (cat integer, UNION integer, TIPO 
varchar ( 22 ), NOMBRE varchar ( 30 ), JURISDICCI varchar ( 14 ), CLASE 
varchar ( 22 ), TRANSITABI varchar ( 24 ), PROVINCIA varchar ( 60 ), PAIS 
varchar ( 15 ), OBSERVACIO varchar ( 50 ), HOJA varchar ( 10 ), FUENTE 
varchar ( 50 ))' 
Finished with error
```

[image: Roads and observation points]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a first guess, I see one issue:

The column name "UNION" is an SQL reserved word, and probably causing the failure. Can you change that name in the original shapefile?